# Convert some Jquery code to Mootools

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools

The code is used for google maps api to autocomplete the search address. I must convert it because of a conflict in my joomla site. How would I achieve the same with Mootools 1.4? Some help will be much appreciated!

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

  initialize();

  $(function() {
    $("#entry_3").autocomplete({
      //This bit uses the geocoder to fetch address values
      source: function(request, response) {
        geocoder.geocode( {'address': request.term }, function(results, status) {
          response($.map(results, function(item) {
            return {
              label:  item.formatted_address,
              value: item.formatted_address,
              latitude: item.geometry.location.lat(),
              longitude: item.geometry.location.lng()
            }
          }));
        })
      },
      //This bit is executed upon selection of an address
      select: function(event, ui) {
        $("#entry_4").val(ui.item.latitude);
        $("#entry_5").val(ui.item.longitude);
        var location = new google.maps.LatLng(ui.item.latitude, ui.item.longitude);
        marker.setPosition(location);
        map.setCenter(location);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

**Edit:
It is wrong to add window.onunload = GUnload; in google maps api v3. It's a v2 function. v3 don't need onunload. And that messed up the autocomplete function.**

Comment: Is the "conflict' because you're using jQuery and Mootools? If so, have you attempted to use jQuery.noConflict() before you attempt doing something of this scale? And if there is a conflict, use "CNTRL+F" and replace all instances of "$" with "jQuery"

Comment: I tried this but with no results.

Comment: What is the error that you are receiving? Understanding the usage of jQuery.noConflict(); is a big deal. There is an answer on this page that has a link to the documentation for just this problem. Let me know if you still retain issues after ensuring that you're '*doing it right*'

Comment: Damn, I forgot to remove a window.onunload event that was not in place... Everything is working now! Thanks. The problem was not in jQuery.noConflict() after all :-)

Comment: I like it. Glad to hear you got it working. Mind creating an "EDIT" in your post and showing where the issue resided so anyone traveling here from the future that sees this can get a quick grasp of what the issue was, and compare their issue to yours to see if they need the same solution? Thanks and good luck!

Comment: It is wrong to add window.onunload = GUnload; in google maps api v3. It's a v2 function. v3 don't need onunload. And that messed up the autocomplete function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to write code in mootools just use
jquery no conflict

```
jQuery.noConflict();
     jQuery(document).ready(function($){
       // you're jquery code

     });
```

http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries